# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 on Junit, but not web app

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4

I'm running Junits on our app server that fail with **Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**.  But, the web application then builds, deploys, and runs fine.  I don't understand how this can happen.  My maven compiler's config looks like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
    <verbose>true</verbose> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And my Junit dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone think of a reason this is failing?

Comment: That looks like you have an old version of java (the JRE, not the compiler) on the app server.

Comment: How do you execture the maven build itself? Make sure it uses a current version of the java runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: I agree it sounds like the JDK used to compile the WAR/Junits is a different version than the JRE used to run the Junits.  What mechanism does Maven use to determine what "Java" to use to run the Junits?  (this is running on Linux).  I have a handful of apps running on this app server, but only one fails its Junits with the version error.  Very strange.

Comment: More specifically, the JDK used to compile the code is newer than the one running the code.  The JVMs are backwards compatible but not forward.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion might be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) is responsible for running JUnit tests.  Try adding this config.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>2.16</version>
  <configuration>
    <jvm>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</jvm>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME on the app server points to Java 6.  So, the app is building using Java 7 (as specified in the compiler plugin), but Maven is using the JAVA_HOME JRE (Java 6) to run Junits in.  The Surefire plugin fixed that.  Thanks everyone!